# C - converting to char * array index to string, and comparing it

Tags: c, arrays, string

Disclaimer: Extreme beginner in C.
I have an array of type char* which gets strings inserted into it.

```
char* arr[100];
```

I am basically trying to compare strings from the indicies of that array, where im trying to do something like
`strcmp(arr[0],"something")`

But they are of a different types and im not sure how to go about solving this conversion issue and i've looked at other questions but it's not really solving my issue.

I tried converting using 

`char str;
strcpy(str,arr[0]);`

However, its still not providing the correct output.

Comment: maybe `char arr[100];` .. `strcmp(arr, "something")`

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: You can't use `char str`, that's not a string, it's a single character (a small integer).  You need either `char str[n]` or `char *str` if you want a string.

Comment: @TomKarzes the second will need a memory allocation before `strcpy(str,arr[0]);`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char* str_cmp = "something";
    char* arr[100] = {"Something1","Something2","Something3"}; //You can declare 100 string here
    int rc = strcmp(arr[0], str_cmp);
        if(rc == 0)
        printf("[%s] equals [%s]\n", arr[0], str_cmp);
    else if(rc < 0)
        printf("[%s] precedes [%s]\n", arr[0], str_cmp);
    else if(rc > 0)
        printf("[%s] follows [%s]\n", arr[0], str_cmp);
    return 0;
}
```

go for additional information about
[strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

**EDIT**

If you want to compare other strings in `arr[100]`, simply try using `for` loop for indexing.

```
for(size_t i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
{
  ///Comparing goes here
}
```

Comment: the only problem i am facing here, is that when the strings are actually equal, the if clause does not get executed and nothing is outputted. but this example works great!

Comment: @user3676224 I am glad that I could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp(arr[0], "something")` on `char* arr[100]` works perfectly fine:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* arr[100];

int main(void)
{
    int r;
    arr[0]="something";
    r = strcmp(arr[0], "something");
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```